# Proving no integer solution exists that makes a polynomial a perfect square

Tags: quadratics, diophantine-equations, integers

The context for this is the following [coding problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler100/problem) on Hackerrank. I'm trying to understand why one of their sample inputs (Sample Input 4) has no solution.

After a bit of math, it comes down to showing that for any natural number $D>100$, the following expression cannot be a natural number.

$$\frac{1 + \sqrt{D^2 -D +1}}{2}$$

I have no idea why that is true. I now just want to check if $\sqrt{D^2 -D +1}$ can be an odd integer for some $D$ or prove that it can never be the case. How does one approach this type of problem for a general quadratic expression under the square root?

Comment: **Basic argument.** Since $D$ is a natural number, so is $D^2-D+1$. But $(D-1)^2 = D^2-2D+1$, so $D^2-D+1$ is almost exactly halfway between $(D-1)^2$ and $D^2$. Since square roots of natural numbers other than perfect squares are irrational, the fraction cannot be a natural number. ETA: This argument only fails for $D = 0$ or $1$, where $D^2-D+1 = 1$ is a perfect square. But it fails for all other natural $D > 1$. Can you complete the argument? **Hint.** Show that for $D > 1$, the argument of the square root is strictly between $(D-1)^2$ and $D^2$.

Comment: @BrianTung thank you, that makes perfect sense and indeed, I can see that the argument in the square root lies between $(D-1)^2$ and $D^2$ and therefore cannot be the square of a natural number. I can accept your comment as the answer, if you post it. Many thanks!

Comment: This is the difference of squares. You can write the formula. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1050570_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $D$ is a natural number, so is $D^2-D+1$. But $(D-1)^2 = D^2-2D+1$, so $D^2-D+1$ is almost exactly halfway between $(D-1)^2$ and $D^2$. Because square roots of natural numbers other than perfect squares are irrational, the fraction cannot be a natural number.

The foregoing argument only fails for $D = 0$ or $1$, where $D^2-D+1 = 1$ is a perfect square. But it works for all other natural numbers $D > 1$. Can you complete this argument? **Hint.** Show that for $D > 1$, $D^2-D+1$ is strictly between $(D-1)^2$ and $D^2$.

Comment: It also fails for integers $D<0$ because then $D^2<D^2-D+1<(D-1)^2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The question was about natural numbers $D$, so I didn't consider those. (In fact, the question posited $D > 100$, but I ignored that detail.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean it as a correction, just noting the extension.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Got it, thanks.